# How to display logs from Android's native modules to react native's metro

Tags: android, react-native, logging, react-native-native-module

I use the command `npx react-native start` to run the Metro of react native,
I just use `console.log()` on my javascript files to log the data to that metro

The problem is when I'm trying to log from my native's android modules, It's not displaying on the metro,

I used `Log.d` and `System.out.print()` but still, I'm not getting the datas

```java
@ReactMethod
public void testMe(Promise promise){
    Log.d("Test", "Test datas");
    System.out.print("Test");
    promise.resolve("success");
}
```

I also use `npx react-native log-android` but it's still not showing there.

Is there a way to log from the android's native module without sending the data to the react native?

PS: I'm also trying to log objects such as `HashMap` if possible.

Comment: Has you found how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While metro is running, Android Native Module logs are visible in Android Studio's Logcat.
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat